# Complications of having architecture i386 in 64 bit system?

Tags: 64-bit, steam, architecture

Steam requires 32 bit architecture. 
I am thinking what can be complications of the command
`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` because all other components of my system and compuation (Matlab, Mathematica) are done in 64 bit architecture.

I am worried about the performance decrease and complexity increase in the system.

---

What can be the complications of having i386 architecture in 64 bit system?

Comment: Just that you need to more disk space to store the two copies of common libraries.

Comment: How much conflicts can happen between 32bit and 64 bit systems in the same system?

Comment: None. 32bits software will use 32bits libraries, 64bits software will use 64bits libraries.

Comment: @dadexix86 Please consider converting your comments to an answer, I know it will be short but it is correct, drop me a comment and I will give you a +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only inconveniente is that that you need more disk space to store the two copies of common libraries.

There is no conflict betweent he software, since 32bits software will use 32bits libraries and 64bits software will use 64bits libraries.

Comment: It would be great to understand how the current bug of upstard/systemd with runit (15x and 16x) can conflict here. I think it is not so easy as you propose.

Comment: I never heard of it, nor I have experienced it... Can you please link it from somewhere?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/284453/16920

Comment: I do not see how that problem has anything to do with multi architecture...

Comment: I just do not know. I just know that I cannot get multiarchitecture work in 15x and 16x, only in 14x.

Comment: That problem has to do with upstart/systemd, as explained in the answer there. It has nothing to do with 32/64 bits...